# Is the regular expression: $(\lambda + a)^*$ equivalent to $a^*$?

Tags: computer-science

I have a question about convert a regular expression to an automaton.
In the middle of the regular expression, appears $(\lambda + a)^*$. 
What I am wondering is: it is not the same of $ a^* $?

If is so, I could simplify the final automaton.
$\lambda$ is the symbol for empty string.

Comment: Is $\lambda$ your notation for the empty string?

Comment: yes it is the notation for empty string.

Comment: Why this is "on hold"? I tagged it incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $(\lambda+a)^*$ and $a^*$ describe the same language.

Depending on which context you meet the task in, you *may or may not* be expected to follow a particular algorithm mindlessly (construct a NFA from the abstract syntax tree of the regex, convert the NFA to a DFA, minimize the DFA).

Otherwise, you can just write down the trivial (one state, one transition) automaton and be done with it.